# What is the best structure to create in firebase storage when uploading photos?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, architecture, firebase-storage

Hello guys so my questions consists of 2 parts.

The first is: **What is the best structure to save images in firebase storage?**

The images uploaded always 'belong' to someone and are always in connection with that person. In my app people can post jobs, and they are able to post job-pictures. So in a way the have to be connected to the persons UID right? I was thinking of a path like this:

```
firebaseStorage/users/${user.uid}/**photos here**
```

So in a way I can find the photos by just looking up the folder with the users UID. Is this a scalable and reasonable approach?

The second question is: **Users will be able to upload 1 to 3 pictures. Should I even be using firebaseStorage?**

I have read other questions and some say that they encoded them into base64 because they are so small. Are these answers outdated? It just feels wrong encoding to base64 when you have a full feature just for images and files.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `uid` is not always the best way to use it as an identifier because if you let the users the posibility to delete the account, then another `uid` is generated. So another approach will be to use as an identifier the `email address`. It's also unique and very easy to use. If you want to use the email address, remember that Firebase does not allow the presence of `.` inside a key and you need to encode the email like this:

> name@mail.com -> name@mail,com

As you probably see, i have changed the `.` (dot) with a `,` (comma).

Firebase [forbidden symbols](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references):

> - . (period)
> - $ (dollar sign)
> - [ (left square bracket)
> - ] (right square bracket)
> - .# (hash or pound sign)
> - / (forward slash)

Regarding the second question, you can use Firebase and for more then 3 pictures and there is no need for encoding them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Alex! Yes this did help a lot :) I will try your approach.

Comment: If my email is jhon,doe@stackoverflow.com your approach will not work

Comment: Yes, it will work. As long as you don't use forbiden symbols, everything will alright. See my updated answer.